# JavaScript map - select one property from array with name

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 3, b: 1},...]
```

and I would like to convert to this array:

```
[{a:1}, {a:2}, {a: 3}]
```

I tried this:

```
array.map(x => {'a': x.a})
```

but this is a mistake (its giving error).
is there any function in JavaScript that can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap implicitly returned object with parenthesis and use the return value of array.map:

```js
let array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 3, b: 1}];
array = array.map(x => ({'a': x.a}));
console.log(array);
```

**And even shorter with ES6 destructuring and shorthand object litteral:**

```js
let array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 3, b: 1}];
array = array.map(({a}) => ({a}));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 6):

You were almost there, just wrap that expression in `()`

```
map(x => ({'a': x.a}))
```

**Demo**

```js
var output = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 3, b: 1}].map(x => ({'a': x.a}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 3, b: 1}].map(element=>({'a': element.a}))
```

Comment: Code should be formatted as code. (Ctrl+K or `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to convert to this array...

If you do not require to create a separate array, it would be better to use `.forEach` and remove the property `b` from the objects.

```js
var arr = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: 3
}, {
  a: 3,
  b: 1
}];

arr.forEach(function(x) {
  delete x.b;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: bad solution goes for creating new one.

Comment: using delete is in general a bad practice as could lead to unexpected beavhior when scaled, you'll better use Obj.assign to create a new object without that property, this give you better control on the application state